# PDF attachment sent via PHP not always working

Tags: php, pdf, encoding, base64, attachment

I made a simple email registration system with a validating md5 hash.  When the validating link has been followed and the account becomes "active", I am trying to send a pdf to the user.  This is working sometimes, and not on others.  I am using the following code:

```
$subject = 'Your free PDF'; 
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 
$headers = "From: info@mysite.com\r\nReply-To: info@mysite.com"; 
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\""; 
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('../../assets/Free PDF.pdf'))); 
ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering 
?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>" 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hi,

Please find attached your free PDF.

~ The Team

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hi,<br>
<br>
Please find attached your free <strong>PDF</strong>.
<br>
~ The Team

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="Free PDF.pdf"  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64  
Content-Disposition: attachment  

<?php echo $attachment; ?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

<?php 
//copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer 
$message = ob_get_clean(); 
//send the email 
$mail_sent = @mail( $email, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

When it doesn't work with an email, it wont work ever to that email address.  For example, someone received it at a yahoo.com address using the web mail.  I tested the same on another, and it worked fine.  It's not that it's going to spam or anything, it goes to the email, then the PDF that is downloaded isn't valid, and appears to differ in size a little.

Comment: It's very simple: do NOT build your own mime emails. Both Swiftmailer and PHPMailer can do all this for you in just a few lines of code, and do it far better.